# How to solve network connection when RUN yarn install in docker image build?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I have a peculiar problem occurring only in the Mac environment. When I run the docker build command to build my Node image, it is not able to fetch the packages, informing that there is a connection problem. This only occurs in the Mac environment. I have a server here where the build is done normally, but this ends up preventing me from doing tests on my machine.

Could anyone tell me what it could be and how to fix it?

[image]

Dockerfile is here:

```
FROM node:16.14-alpine3.15 as builder

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
COPY tsconfig.json .
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16.14-alpine3.15 as production

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir logs

COPY package*.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install

COPY --from=builder /home/node/app/dist /usr/src/app/dist

EXPOSE 3333
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I already tried adding the following flags in the yarn install command:

`RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --no-cache --production --network-timeout 100000`

All together or individually, but to no avail. I also removed the proxies, also without success.

`RUN yarn config delete https-proxy RUN yarn config delete proxy.`

However, I noticed that this error only occurs with v1.22 of Yarn. When using the berry version the same does not happen.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I haven't found the solution for this specific case. And I could notice the same problem when building other images. I ended up running the build over ssh on a debian server. I noticed that this only happens on Mac (m1 and intel) and only with yarn v1. If you find the solution, could you share it with us?

Comment: I tried `--network-timeout 100000` and it did build once then it complained again, maybe try increasing the value to an absurd number. I also have this issue on mac :(

Comment: This is in older node images; the solution (2023) is to add `RUN yarn set version stable` before you install, which will upgrade you to (currently) v3.6.3

Comment: `yarn set version stable` solved my issue

Answer (score 5):

I drop this answer here, because nothing about proxy helped in my case.

**TL;DR**
The version check URL redirects and that causes confusion to yarn

So, I went on to examine typical archaic tools, like verbosity check, curl and dig.

So, first thing first, I tried to check verbose output:

Bingo #1.

```
verbose 0.181073051 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
[1/4] Resolving packages...                                                       
success Already up-to-date.                                                                                                                                          
Done in 0.12s.                                                                                                                                                       
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...                                                                                           
verbose 33.254841183 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".                                                                               
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...                                                                                           
verbose 66.292530305 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".                                                                               
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...                                                                                           
verbose 99.329186881 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".                                                                               
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...                                                                                           
verbose 132.366749502 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
```

Why not getting an answer from yarnpkg.com? This is insane... So, let's see if this resolves:

```
$ dig yarnpkg.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.7-1+b1-Debian <<>> yarnpkg.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55602
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 9cf3b6f8b290069dbbe8ca8763501b11ea79617323c673e6 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yarnpkg.com.                   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yarnpkg.com.            300     IN      A       104.18.126.100
yarnpkg.com.            300     IN      A       104.16.171.99

;; Query time: 11 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 19 18:43:13 EEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

It does!!! (?)

So, let's see what I get from it, by using curl

```
$ curl https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version
Redirecting to https://classic.yarnpkg.com/latest-version
```

WHAT? A redirect? Ok, this is new..

I tried to set the url to check version not to be yarnpkg.com, but classic.yarnpkg.com, but I couldn't find the yarn configuration variable to use.

So, I used `/etc/hosts`.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.7-1+b1-Debian <<>> classic.yarnpkg.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35092
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 72636a6924283d51c4127a8463501bbb42e53d34835e8402 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;classic.yarnpkg.com.           IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
classic.yarnpkg.com.    300     IN      CNAME   yarnpkg.netlify.com.
yarnpkg.netlify.com.    20      IN      A       3.64.200.242
yarnpkg.netlify.com.    20      IN      A       34.141.11.154

;; Query time: 59 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Oct 19 18:46:03 EEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 138
```

Set the first IP to yarnpkg.com

```
# /etc/hosts
34.141.48.9     yarnpkg.com
```

BINGO!!! Yarn command finished instantly.

```
$ yarn 
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.12s.
$
```

Comment: Thank you for going through the pedantic troubleshooting steps needed to identify the issue. The old "It's DNS. It's always DNS" answer comes back... I generally don't like mucking with my /etc/hosts file like this because eventually I will forget I set this so when it ultimately changes I will spend way too much time before I look at my hosts file. But thank you for getting this out. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I'd rather not having to, but I couldn't find a variable for version check url. Trust me, I went through the documentation quite thoroughly. What is funny, in my office PC, which runs the same OS, I didn't have to do it, it worked out of the box... Maybe it's about curl configuration, following redirects etc.

Answer (score 1):

For me, its solved using this :

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
```

and then:

```
yarn config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
```

Answer (score 0):

could be because of a docker network that is blocking your access

try `docker network ls` to list all networks and `docker network prune` to delete unused

and try installing again